# sql - select ids of items in 1st table that have a foreign key for second table by average range

Tags: mysql

I have a database of a cowshed that have two tables:

1. place_of_cow(cow_id, block_id)
2. cow_details(nickname, cow_id, age) - **age of cow in months**

Table place_of_cow was created like this:

```
CREATE TABLE place_of_cow (
  block_id       INT  NOT NULL,
  cow_id       INT NOT NULL, 
FOREIGN KEY cow_detailsFK (cow_id)
    REFERENCES cow_details (cow_id)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION
);
```

And the values that i inserted are:

```
INSERT INTO place_of_cow
VALUES (1, 1), (1, 5), (1, 6), (2, 2), (2, 7), (3, 3), (4, 4), (4, 8), (4, 9);
```

Table cow_details was created like this:

```
CREATE TABLE cow_details (
  cow_id       INT  NOT NULL,
  nickname     CHAR(25) NOT NULL, 
  age          INT NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT cow_detailsPK PRIMARY KEY (cow_id)
);
```

And the values that i inserted are:

```
INSERT INTO cow_details 
  (cow_id,nickname,age)
VALUES
    (1,'hedva',16),
    (2,'tali',16),
    (3,'cow3',14),
    (4,'cow4',9),
    (5,'cow5',16),
    (6,'cow6',7),
    (7,'cow7',4),
    (8,'cow8',5),
    (9,'cow9',9),
    (10,'cow10',7),
    (12,'cow12',3),
    (13,'cow13',1),
    (14,'cow14',1),
    (15,'cow15',20),
    (16,'cow16',22);
```

I'm trying to show all the block_ids from table **place_of_cow** where the **average age** of the cows in each block_id is above 10 months.
I've tried the following code:

```
select distinct p.block_id from place_of_cow as p
where exists
(
select c.cow_id from cow_details as c where c.cow_id = p.cow_id
group by c.cow_id having avg(c.age) > 10
);
```

but the result is:

block_id:
1
2
3

block_id 2 is not supposed to be in the result. what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
select p.block_id
from place_of_cow p 
inner join cow_details d on p.cow_id = d.cow_id
group by p.block_id
having avg(d.age) > 10
```

You need to group on `block_id`, not `cow_id`, since the aggregation has to be done with respect to the block, and not the cow.

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/745f2b/5)

Comment: No worries, you were almost there.